# partition in oracle

Tags: oracle

> CREATE TABLE temp_stud as select * from STUD_MAST
>
> PARTITION BY RANGE(ADM_DT)
>
> (
>
> PARTITION temp_stud1 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('02/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY')),
>
> PARTITION temp_stud2 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('03/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY')),
>
> PARTITION temp_stud3 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('04/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY')),
>
> PARTITION temp_stud4 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('05/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY'))
>
> );

I am getting a missing left parenthesis error for above table creation can anyone tell me what is the issue in above creation

Note: ADM_DT is a date column with data type char(8) and storing format YYMMDD

Answer (score 0):

Please use below SQL. The Creation of Partition has be part of Create table.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_stud   
    PARTITION BY RANGE(ADM_DT)

    (

    PARTITION temp_stud1 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('02/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY')),

    PARTITION temp_stud2 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('03/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY')),

    PARTITION temp_stud3 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('04/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY')),

    PARTITION temp_stud4 VALUES LESS THAN(TO_DATE('05/01/2000','MM/DD/YYYY'))

    )
    as select * from STUD_MAST;
```

Comment: i am getting  error code ORA-14036 partition bound value too large for column

Comment: ADM_DT data type is char(8) and i cannot change it

Comment: @Robert In your question you said "Note: ADM_DT is a date". Maybe you should correct that.

Comment: "Note: ADM_DT is a date" - now you say it's a string. Which is is? If it is a string (why!?) what format - if YYYYMMDD then you can partition on a string too, instead of on a date?

Comment: hello guys ADM_DT is a date but its data type in char(8)

Comment: @Robert Then why do you declare partition boundary as date and if it is not then why `mm/dd/yyyy`, it is 10 symbols long?